# What is the correct way to create a large input text using Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, forms, zurb-foundation

I've read the documentation about [forms](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/typography.php) and there is nothing saying about how to make input texts larger. Larger I mean, for example, as the Grooveshark's search box was before, with bigger typography and dimensions:

[image: A text box like that would be cool :)]

I've read the [typography](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/typography.php) but it talks about headers, lists, etc. Probably there is a way to apply this to the input text, but I am really new to Foundation and I do not know the right way to do that. I saw also that, for [buttons](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/buttons.php), you can control how large they are using the respective classes, "large", "medium", "small", and "tiny", but what if I want to make my input text as large as the button?

So far, I have a basic input form as following:

```
<form> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="ten mobile-three columns">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Type here what you want" />
    </div>
    <div class="two mobile-one columns">
      <a class="button expand postfix">Search</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no correct way as per Foundation's UI toolset. You will have to apply your own CSS to application.css in order to achieve this.

For example:

```
input[type=text] {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Note that this works only in this particular example, you would need to add some `#id` to the search input element in order not to set this style to all input texts.

Comment: I've added also the "height" attribute. Thanks!

Comment: Also, line-height might need adjustment for the postfix.